# Using LAG/LEAD with missing PK on alternate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to work with the following table in SQL Server 2012:

```
EMPID    JOB_TITLE            SALARY
------------------------------------
1234     SALES                56000
NULL     NULL                 54000
1235     MARKETING            72000
NULL     NULL                 71000
```

The table originates from an excel extract, for which I import using OPENROWSET.

I need to derive the "previous" salary value, which you can assume always resides in the following record in it's natural order in the table, and display it as a new column.

Expected output:

```
EMPID    JOBTITLE            SALARY    PREV_SALARY
--------------------------------------------------
1234     BUSINESS ANALYST     56000     54000
1235     SALES MANAGER        72000     71000
```

Obviously, a little challenging, because there no PK on the following row, I cannot accurately use the LEAD function, if I cannot identify the value to "partition" the record with.  Any ideas?

I've included the same values/code:

```
INSERT INTO #EMP 
VALUES (1234, 'Sales', 56000), 
       (NULL, NULL, 54000),
       (1235, 'Marketing', 72000),
       (NULL, NULL, 70500) 
                                
SELECT 
    EMPID, 
    JOBTITLE,
    SAL,
    LEAD(SAL,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS PREV_SAL
FROM 
    #EMP       
WHERE 
    EMPID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Can you load it into a table with an `IDENTITY()` (while preserving order as it is in the excel)?

Comment: @HoneyBadger  - I was able to successfully implement this! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You can answer your own question, if you feel it could be helpful for others in similar circumstances.

Comment: @HoneyBadger  Done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Honeybadger's suggestion, I implemented the IDENTITY(1,1) attribute when creating the temporary landing table. This captured the natural row sequence as I loaded the data. Works like a charm!

```
CREATE TABLE #EMP 
(
 EMPID INT
, JOBTITLE NVARCHAR(19)
, SAL INT
, ROW_SEQ INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
) 



INSERT INTO #EMP 
VALUES (1234, 'Sales', 56000), 
       (NULL, NULL, 54000),
       (1235, 'Marketing', 72000),
       (NULL, NULL, 70500) 
 
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    EMPID, 
    JOBTITLE,
    SAL,
    LEAD(SAL,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY ROW_SEQ ) AS PREV_SAL
FROM  #EMP )  T WHERE EMPID IS NOT NULL
```

Outputs:

```
EMPID   JOBTITLE    SAL     PREV_SAL
1234    Sales       56000   54000
1235    Marketing   72000   70500
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is no column that defines the ordering of the rows, the question cannot be solved - rows of a SQL table are *unordered* by design.

**If** you have an ordering column you can do:

```
select *
from (
    select e.*, lead(salary) over(order by id) as prev_salary
    from employee e
) t
where empid is not null
```

This assumes that non-null and null rows always properly interleave. If that's not the case, then I would recommend some gaps-and-islands technique, as in:

```
select max(empid) as empid, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then job_title end) as job_title, 
    max(case when rn = 1 then salary    end) as salary,
    max(case when rn = 2 then salary    end) as prev_salary
from (
    select e.*, row_number() over(partition by grp order by empid) rn
    from (
        select e.*, count(empid) over(order by id) as grp
        from employee e
    ) t
) t
group by grp
```